# Buddypress translate

Tags: buddypress

Can't get buddypress 1.6.4. to translate. I've added both .po and .mo files to wordpress in the plugins directory inside buddypress/bp-languages/

files are called 
**buddypress-mysite.po** and
**buddypress-mysite.mo**

I also created **bp-custom.php** in {WP-ROOT}/wp-content/plugins       and added this code:

```
<?php
define( 'BPLANG', 'mysite' );
if ( file_exists( BP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/bp-languages/buddypress-' . BPLANG . '.po' ) ) {
    load_textdomain( 'buddypress', BP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/bp-languages/buddypress-' . BPLANG . '.po' );
}?>
```

still cant get it to work :( I've done some debugging and it seems like the bp-custom.php is reading correctly on the domain, but it won't trigger the .mo and .po files to translate the actual page.

Can anyone please help? I really need this working!!

Comment: Have you followed the directions for adding custom translations here:https://codex.buddypress.org/translations/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what languague you want but i have installed [buddypress-translations](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-translations/) and it worked fine.

Comment: This is not really a helpful response to the question. Consider adding things like this as comment to the question instead of an answer. Also consider adding some relevant code to help the user fixing his problems.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't need to edit code for that, i just installed the plugin and it worked fine. My site is in spanish, maybe he is trying to translate to another lenguague and it has already be done on that plugin.